# Installing Hue, permission denied error?

Tags: hadoop, hue

I'm getting the following while trying to build Hue:

```
(6211) *** Controller starting at Thu Aug  8 11:29:50 2013
Should start 1 new children
Controller.spawn_children(number=1)
$HADOOP_HOME=
$HADOOP_BIN=/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop
$HIVE_CONF_DIR=~/hive-0.10.0/conf
$HIVE_HOME=~/hive-0.10.0
find: `~/hive-0.10.0/lib': No such file or directory
$HADOOP_CLASSPATH=:
$HADOOP_OPTS=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties
$HADOOP_CONF_DIR=~/hive-0.10.0/conf:/usr/local/hadoop/conf
$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce
CWD=/usr/local/hue/desktop/conf
Executing /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop jar /usr/local/hue/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/../../java-lib/BeeswaxServer.jar --beeswax 8002 --desktop-host 127.0.0.1 --desktop-port 8888 --query-lifetime 604800000 --metastore 8003
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1879)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:119)
```

I've changed the configuration file so it doesn't use hue but the user that I'm logged in as which has read and write permissions in the hadoop dfs, hadoop, hive, etc. Not sure why it's doing this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is starting to start Beeswax in /usr/local/hue/desktop/conf. Beeswax should be running as the 'hue' user by default (https://github.com/cloudera/hue/blob/master/desktop/core/src/desktop/supervisor.py#L67) so it  need to be writable by 'hue'.

Comment: so what files need to be writable by the hue user?